# Jest testing issue

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Hi all I am trying to test the below code using Jest however I am receiving an error of mData not defined when I am running the test. Please take a look at the code below and if possible please let me know where I am going wrong here. Thanks in advance.

```
function createMilkShakeData(mData) {

 }

 describe("milkshake Data Generator", () => {
 it("creates correct data structure ", () => {
  const mData = [
    "milkshake1/milkshake1flavour",
    "milkshake1/milkshake1flavor2",
    "milkshake2/milkshake2flavour",
    "milkshake2/milkshake2flavour2",
    "milkshake1/milkshake1flavour3",
    "flavour3",
    "milkshake3/flavour3flavour1",
    "milkshake4"
  ];

  const expectedResult = [
    {
      title: "milkshake1",
      data: ["milkshake1flavour", "milkshake1flavour2", "milkshake1flavour3"]
    },
    { title: "milkshake2", data: ["milkshake2flavour", "milkshake2flavour2"] },
    { title: "milkshake3", data: ["milkshake3flavour1"] }
  ];

  const actualResult = createMilkShakeData(mData);
  expect(actualResult).toMatchObject(expectedResult);
});
});

module.exports = createMilkShakeData
module.exports = mData
```

***code from test file below***

```
    const createMilkShakeData = require('./milkshake')

    const data = require('./milkshake')

    test('milkshake Data Generator', () => {

    const actualResult = createMilkShakeData(mData);
  expect(actualResult).toMatchObject(expectedResult)}
  )
```

Comment: What you've posted makes no sense. You're requiring twice to different names from the same file, you have a test in the file you imply is the code under test and the function has no implementation. It's hard to see why you expected this to work.

Comment: Like @jonrsharpe said you need to add a bit more information.

Answer (score 0):

`mData` is not defined in the global scope of your first file - it is only defined in the function's scope - in this case `it` from Jest. If you need to export it, defined it in the global scope (i.e. before your "describe").